# SocialEngine 4 signup process

Tags: zend-framework

Im working in socialEngine 4 and i would really like to know if anybody have an idea of how to remove the following blocks for the signup process:

*Create account
*Create Profile
*Add photo.
*Invite friends...

For now i just want to register an email and the user for a landing page but when the users input the username and the email and click "Send" the create profile and change photo windows are shown (as the normal signup process) and i want that when the user put the username and email  and click send, the success page is shown

I did search in the internet for something like this  and i found

=">How to remove profile info step during signup process in socialengine4 php framework?

the query that is presented solves the problem i have? or for the profile information?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 0):

The sign up process is defined in the database. Take a look at the engine4_user_signup table and you will see the following;

```
signup_id   class                       order   enable
1           User_Plugin_Signup_Account     1    1
2           User_Plugin_Signup_Fields      2    1
3           User_Plugin_Signup_Photo       3    1
4           User_Plugin_Signup_Invite      4    0
```

What you can do is just edit the row 'user_plugin_signup_photo' and set 'enable' to 0. You can also change the order of the sign up process.

The other option is to do the following;

```
 1. Sign into your website as an administrator
 2. Click 'admin' (top right navigation bar)
 3. Under the 'Settings' tab click on 'Sign Up Process'
 4. Then select if you want to 'give the users the option upon sign up'
```

Hope this helps

sign into your website as an administrator